# Sharing database connection pool between Spring Boot apps running Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jndi, connection-pooling

My current production setup requires me to share Oracle database connection pools between multiple Spring Boot apps where each app runs via an embedded Tomcat instance.

What options do I have to share the database connection pool among these Spring Boot apps?

Is JNDI an option? If so, could someone explain how storing the connection pool details in say LDAP accessed via JNDI works?

Comment: Connection pooling can be configured within your app OR within the appserver. If these individual apps do not even share the appserver (they have an embedded Tomcat) then I think you are out of options. If they would be on the same appserver, it would be easy of course via JNDI.

Comment: @GergelyBacso so there is no mechanism to share the connection pool for this setup?

Comment: No, not that I know of.